# Como retornar un arreglo desde un WebService SOAP creado en PHP?

Tags: php

Saludos a todos y de antemano muchas gracias por sus aportaciones. Yo desarrollo en PHP sin embargo tengo apenas un par de días que comencé con web services. Ya desarrolle algunos básicos y no tuve problemas, sin embargo desarrolle uno ya un poco mas avanzado pero estoy teniendo problemas porque al querer consumir mi web service en vb.net me surge un error que dice 'La respuesta no es un codigo XML correcto'. Este web service recibe un Id de entrada y debe retornar varios parametros y creo que es aqui donde esta el problema, solo que no logro identificarlo. Les comparto mi codigo y nuevamente mil gracias.

```php
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8');
require_once("../functions/nusoapLib/nusoap.php");
$server = new nusoap_server();
$server->configureWSDL('ServiciosPublicos', 'urn:ServiciosPublicos');

// Parametros de entrada
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(  'paramsIn',
                                'complexType',
                                'struct',
                                'all',
                                '',
                                array('serviceId' => array('name' => 'serviceId','type' => 'xsd:id'))
);
// Parametros de Salida
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(  'paramsOut', 
                                'complexType', 
                                'struct', 
                                'all', 
                                '',
                                array(
                                    'codigoRes' => array('name' => 'codigoRes', 'type' => 'xsd:int'),
                                    'resultado' => array('name' => 'resultado', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
                                    'servicio'  => array('name' => 'servicio',  'type' => 'xsd:string'),
                                    'fuente'    => array('name' => 'fuente',    'type' => 'xsd:string'),
                                    'nombres'   => array('name' => 'nombres',   'type' => 'xsd:string'),
                                    'domicilio' => array('name' => 'domicilio', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
                                    'estatus'   => array('name' => 'estatus',   'type' => 'xsd:string'))
);

$server->register(  'Consultar', // nombre del metodo o funcion
                    array('paramsIn' => 'tns:paramsIn'), // parametros de entrada
                    array('return' => 'tns:paramsOut'), // parametros de salida
                    'urn:ServiciosPublicos', // namespace
                    'urn:ServiciosPublicos#Consultar', // soapaction debe ir asociado al nombre del metodo
                    'rpc', // style
                    'encoded', // use
                    'Funcion para consultar los datos de una solicitud' // documentation
);

function Consultar($serviceId) {
    include("../../functions/cnn.php");

    $codigoRes = 0;
    $resultado = "La solicitud fue correcta";
    $servicio = "";
    $fuente = "";
    $nombres = "";
    $domicilio = "";
    $estatus = "";

    $cnn = cnn("servicios_publicos");
    $str = "select srv.servicio, fnt.fuente, sol.nombres, sol.domicilio, sol.estatus
    from solicitudes sol
    inner join servicios srv on srv.idservicio = sol.idservicio
    inner join fuentes fnt on fnt.idfuente = sol.idfuente
    inner join generales.localidades loc ON loc.idlocalidad = sol.idlocalidad
    where sol.idsolicitud = ?;";
    $qry = $cnn -> prepare($str);
    $qry -> bind_param("i", $serviceId);
    if (!$qry -> execute()) {
        $codigoRes = 1;
        $resultado = "Ocurrio un error: ".$qry -> error;
    }
    else {
        $qry -> store_result();
        if ($qry -> num_rows == 1) {
            $qry -> bind_result($servicio, $fuente, $nombres, $domicilio, $estatus);
            $qry -> fetch();
        }
        else {
            $codigoRes = 2;
            $resultado = "No se pudo encontrar el registro solicitado";
        }
    }

    $qry -> close();

    return array(
        'codigoRes' => $codigoRes,
        'resultado' => $resultado,
        'servicio'  => $servicio,
        'fuente'    => $fuente,
        'nombres'   => $nombres,
        'domicilio' => $domicilio,
        'estatus'   => $estatus
    );
}

$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
@$server->service(file_get_contents("php://input"));
?>
```

Comment: Además de la parte de servidor, puede compartir también la parte de cliente y el código del sito web que ejecuta todo??

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a una aplicación que me encontré en google que se llama wizdl.exe, pude encontrar el detalle. El problema no era como consumía el web service desde VB.Net ni si quiera era error de programación del web service en PHP con NuSoap, **el ejemplo que puse es correcto**, funciona a la perfección; El problema aquí es que al momento de ver wsdl el xml me lo daba correcto y nunca me mostraba errores de PHP hasta que wizdl.exe me lo notifico.

El detalle aquí es que la ruta hacia el script que contiene la conexión a la BD estaba mal, la corregí y todo funciono de maravilla.